# PyQt - Update QTableView data after db update

Tags: python, qt, sqlite, pyqt

I am writing a pyqt5 based application, I am fetching data from SQLite database
and displaying it using QTableView and data change is only possible in the backend SQLite.

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName(r"C:\Users\vaas\AppData\Local\Temp\uniprotect\unidb.db")
db.open()
projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
projectModel.setQuery("select * from ledgerstats",db)
self.tableView.setModel(projectModel)
```

How can I refresh, the QTabeView data when the data was modified in the SQLite database (by any other applications)?

Thanks,
Vaas.

Comment: I was hoping the [notification](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html#notification-1) feature would solve this, because the qt sqlite driver does support it. However, after some testing, it only seems to work for *internal* events; the equivalent external events are ignored. So it looks like the only option is to use polling.

Comment: I also need notification when db is updated, I do not find similar event from qt docs. Finially I am using polling.